# Maintenance Page via Apache when Tomcat is down

Tags: apache2, site-maintenance, tomcat

I have an Apache2, sitting in front of Tomcat7 via ajp, all on Ubuntu. What I want to do is serve a simple static page with Apache when I perform maintenance.

I found this nice [tutorial](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Redirect-Site-to-Maintenance-Page-using-Apache-and-HTAccess), but I am not that firm on Apache.

```
ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/maintenance

  ##For maintenancepage
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !/maintenance.html
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
  ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html

  #Directory settings omitted..

  ProxyPass /maintenance.html !
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

This is my virtual host configuration file in /sites-available/

---

I expected: when creating a file `maintenance.enable` in `var/www/maintenance`, all requests are answered with the `maintenance.html` page.

But sadly, nothing ever happens. Is my DocumentRoot wrong? Is my ProxyPass setting wrong?

Comment: Did you create `/var/www/maintenance/maintenance.html` and can you access it directly at `http://example.com/maintenance.html`?